# How to detect internet speed in PHP?

Tags: php, performance

How can I create a PHP page that will detect the user's internet speed and show it on the page?  Something like,

> Your internet speed is ??? Kbps

Comment: php script is executed in server, guess that will not determine the users internet speed ... rather flash or java would do that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This might not be completely what you're looking for (read the bold part), but I doubt if anything else is possible.

*This script sends 512 KB of HTML comments to your client. Parsing that HTML may add to the total transfer time, so **don't take this as your raw download speed.***

Quoted from: [PHP Speed test](http://jan.moesen.nu/code/php/speedtest/index.php?numKB=512)

Source is here:

[http://jan.moesen.nu/code/php/speedtest/index.php?source=1](http://web.archive.org/web/20111025073301/http://jan.moesen.nu/code/php/speedtest/index.php?source=1)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 11):

```
<?php
$kb=1024;
echo "streaming $kb Kb...<!-";
flush();
$time = explode(" ",microtime());
$start = $time[0] + $time[1];
for($x=0;$x<$kb;$x++){
    echo str_pad('', 1024, '.');
    flush();
}
$time = explode(" ",microtime());
$finish = $time[0] + $time[1];
$deltat = $finish - $start;
echo "-> Test finished in $deltat seconds. Your speed is ". round($kb / $deltat, 3)."Kb/s";
?>
```

Comment: **Do not click through to the triquitips demo URL**, the site offers an demo of the script which seems to attempt to autosubscribe you to something.

Comment: @Exit - I removed the link from the post. (I'm not sure if it was or was not malicious, and I'd rather not find out!)

Answer (score 6):

For example by timing AJAX request on client side. That way you can figure approximate download speed, but not upload. For uploading, sending large AJAX POST request can handle it.

With jQuery and `$.ajax` it's pretty trivial to do.

Comment: You'd just have to account for stuff like Comcast's Powerboost thing.

Comment: I guess you would have more upvotes if you provided a code example.

Answer (score 5):

By user uploading a file to your server. Then you divide file size in kb with time passed in seconds. You then get kb/s (upload speed).

```
$kb = round(filesize("file.jpg") / 1024); // 500kb
$time = time() - $start; // 5s
$speed = round($kb / $time); // 100kb/s
```

Comment: However, what is `$start`?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me :

```
    $kb=512;
    echo "streaming $kb Kb...<!-";
    flush();
    $time = explode(" ",microtime());
    $start = $time[0] + $time[1];
    for($x=0;$x<$kb;$x++){
        echo str_pad('', 1024, '.');
        flush();
    }
    $time = explode(" ",microtime());
    $finish = $time[0] + $time[1];
    $deltat = $finish - $start;
    echo "-> Test finished in $deltat seconds. Your speed is ". round($kb / $deltat, 3)."Kb/s";
    ?>
```

I got this from [here](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2006/05/31/determine-connection-speed-with-php/).

Answer (score -3):

Not really possible. PHP is server sided, detecting speed would be client sided.

You may find work arounds to do it, tho.