# Check for end user's ISP internet speed for better video streaming

Tags: php, drupal-6, video-streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to detect internet speed in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529620/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-php)

I have a drupal website where I am showing some video content. So as a new addition, I want to have a new facility as to check the end user's internet speed and automatically determine which version of the video to show to the end user. Though the person will have a choice to change the versions. But the default will be loaded based on the internet speed.

So is there any way that I can determine the internet speed and show the a low/high resolution version ? In PHP ofcourse.

Comment: Check this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529620/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-php

Comment: checked this one earlier but didn't helped. Always shows more than 512 KB for the download check. Anyway, I will do some R7D on this file.