# test network speed with php and output buffering turned on

Tags: php

I'm using a php script that outputs a file to the client using output buffering.

I have to use output buffering because of the way the script works. Without OB it's easy to test a start and an end time with an echo in between and show the difference in time, but when using OB the time is near zero because the echo output is put locally in the buffer and the buffer is sent to the network in a second momemt without the php script been aware of the process.

Is there a way the test the network speed in the very same script with OB turned on?

```
header('X-Accel-Buffering: yes');

$start_time = microtime(true);

echo $data;  // near zero time

ob_flush();
flush(); // test this speed ??

$end_time = microtime(true);

$speed = strlen($data) / ($end_time - $start_time);
```

Comment: You can not really "measure network speed" that way. Just because PHP has “send” its data, does not mean it has arrived at the client in full as well.

Comment: Without OB you can measure the time it takes to transfer data from the script to the client. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529620/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-php

Comment: I'm sorry to insist, but you can. I have provided a link, thanks.