# How to get time it takes to load .mp4 file

Tags: php, video

I would like to include a video into a website. I need no help with that. But for improving the loading time, I would like to check the internet speed of the user with **pure php** and then decided to load  the video immediately if the internet speed is fast enough and it takes maximum 2 seconds to download that video. else I would like to show an image and give the user to load the video after the rest of the page is already shown.

For giving you an idea what it should look like hava look at this page: https://rocketlabusa.com/

I do already have some code and need just some help with getting the internet speed. I'm able to develop the rest on my own.

Thanks!

That's my code:

```
<?php
define ( "urlToVideo", "someVideo.mp4" );

define ( "sizeOfMovieInBytes", filesize ( urlToVideo ) );

define ( "speedOfInternetConnectionInBytesPerSecond", 1 ); /* this is what I need */

if (sizeOfMovieInBytes / speedOfInternetConnectionInBytesPerSecond > 2) { // if it takes more than 2 Seconds to load the movie
    /*
     * a image should be shown and a play button for enabling the user to load the video after the rest of the website has loaded
     */
} else { // if it takes 2 seconds or less
    /*
     * the video should be loaded immediately and the image and played immediately
     */
}

?>
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is something you'd have to do with JS as this is dom related. Also your solution of using an image sounds like a good idea. Because if the users internet is fast they wont notice its an image as the video will load super fast and if its not it sits there as an image till the video loads then it can start playing when ready. This really allready happens I dont think you really need to be recording the users speed.

Comment: This answer provides some good solutions. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5529620/how-to-detect-internet-speed-in-php

Comment: This is *almost* impossible with pure PHP, but there is no real practical way of doing it. It would be much easier to make a non-render-blocking JS file that is <1kb, which first loads an image and then asynchronously loads the video.